How to avoid losing CSS Grouping Selector formatting when formating with Beauty extension
I have the CSS group selector:
h1, h2, p {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

When I use Beauty (or Prettier) to formating code, I lose the formatting:
h1,
h2,
p{
    text-align: left;
    color: #f40823;
}

How should I configure Prettier or Beauty extension?

Unfortunately, there is no specific way provided by "Prettier" to achieve this but you can achieve this by some methods. The first method is to disable the "Prettier" extension for the CSS file extension but I don't think anyone would want that. The second method is to use /* prettier-ignore  */ of the line above the desired block of CSS code. This disables the "Prettier" extension only for the block of the CSS below that particular line. After saving the CSS file this will not get formatted as it should not get.
/* prettier-ignore  */
h1, h2, p {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}

